# How to get CSV data (as obtained from GoogleSheets - Google Python API) into a table-format (dataframe)?

Tags: python

I have written a piece of code that gets data from a Google-Sheets doc through a path defined by IFTTT, DialogFlow and Hiroku, this happens through this snippet:

```
# Finding a workbook by name and opening the first sheet
sheet = client.open("IFTTT_Webhooks").sheet1

# Extract and print all of the values
list_of_answers = sheet.get_all_records()

#put the values from the list_of_answers into a csv and store locallyy.
with open('user_answers.csv', 'w') as myfile:
    wr = csv.writer(myfile, quoting=csv.QUOTE_ALL)
    wr.writerow(list_of_answers)
```

If I open 'user_answers.csv' the csv looks as such:

> [{'Date/Time': 'February 19, 2020 at 09:49PM', 'Intent':
>   'poll_completed', 'Statement 1': 'yes', 'Statement 2': 'Sometimes',
>   'Statement 3': 'sometimes', 'Statement 4': 'yes'}, {'Date/Time':
>   'February 19, 2020 at 09:50PM', 'Intent': 'poll_completed', 'Statement
>   1': 'yes', 'Statement 2': 'never', 'Statement 3': 'never', 'Statement
>   4': 'no'}, {'Date/Time': 'February 19, 2020 at 10:48PM', 'Intent':
>   'poll_completed', 'Statement 1': 'yes', 'Statement 2': 'often',
>   'Statement 3': 'sometimes', 'Statement 4': 'yes'}, {'Date/Time':
>   'February 20, 2020 at 12:14AM', 'Intent': 'poll_completed', 'Statement
>   1': 'now', 'Statement 2': 'often', 'Statement 3': 'sometimes',
>   'Statement 4': 'yes'}]

How can I get this data in a table-format with the columns as such and their respective values:

```
Date/time,                    Statement 1, Statement 2, Statement 3, Statement 4
February 19, 2020 at 09:49PM.  yes         Sometimes    Sometimes.   no
```

It's ok if the csv format stays as is. But I want to be able to work with data more effectively in another file. So I want to create I guess a dataframe that considers this new (requested) table-format. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: You should be able to load an array of dictionaries into pandas simply by using df = pd.DataFrame(csv), where csv is a variable pointing to the list of dictionaries

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ive not pulled from google but maybe change the code to something like this so it pulls directly into a dataframe?

```
import gspread
from oauth2client.service_account import ServiceAccountCredentials
import pandas as pd

scope = ['https://spreadsheets.google.com/feeds',
         'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive']

credentials = ServiceAccountCredentials.from_json_keyfile_name(
         'ForMedium-8f02213e02aa.json', scope) # Your json file here

gc = gspread.authorize(credentials)

wks = gc.open("NYC subway data").sheet1

data = wks.get_all_values()
headers = data.pop(0)

df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns=headers)
```

Comment: This worked perfectly, without adding too much code. Thanks a lot James.

Comment: is there a way btw to exclude the row-numbers?

Answer (score 1):

You have list of dictionares so you should use `DictWriter()`

- first I get keys from first row to have headers
- next I create writer which can work with dictionares
- finally I write headers and all data

Code:

```
import csv

data = [{'Date/Time': 'February 19, 2020 at 09:49PM', 'Intent': 'poll_completed', 'Statement 1': 'yes', 'Statement 2': 'Sometimes', 'Statement 3': 'sometimes', 'Statement 4': 'yes'}, {'Date/Time': 'February 19, 2020 at 09:50PM', 'Intent': 'poll_completed', 'Statement 1': 'yes', 'Statement 2': 'never', 'Statement 3': 'never', 'Statement 4': 'no'}, {'Date/Time': 'February 19, 2020 at 10:48PM', 'Intent': 'poll_completed', 'Statement 1': 'yes', 'Statement 2': 'often', 'Statement 3': 'sometimes', 'Statement 4': 'yes'}, {'Date/Time': 'February 20, 2020 at 12:14AM', 'Intent': 'poll_completed', 'Statement 1': 'now', 'Statement 2': 'often', 'Statement 3': 'sometimes', 'Statement 4': 'yes'}]

headers = data[0].keys()

with open('user_answers.csv', 'w') as f:
    csv_writer = csv.DictWriter(f, headers)
    csv_writer.writeheader()
    csv_writer.writerows(data)
```

---

You can also use `pandas.DataFrame` directly

```
import pandas as pd

data = [{'Date/Time': 'February 19, 2020 at 09:49PM', 'Intent': 'poll_completed', 'Statement 1': 'yes', 'Statement 2': 'Sometimes', 'Statement 3': 'sometimes', 'Statement 4': 'yes'}, {'Date/Time': 'February 19, 2020 at 09:50PM', 'Intent': 'poll_completed', 'Statement 1': 'yes', 'Statement 2': 'never', 'Statement 3': 'never', 'Statement 4': 'no'}, {'Date/Time': 'February 19, 2020 at 10:48PM', 'Intent': 'poll_completed', 'Statement 1': 'yes', 'Statement 2': 'often', 'Statement 3': 'sometimes', 'Statement 4': 'yes'}, {'Date/Time': 'February 20, 2020 at 12:14AM', 'Intent': 'poll_completed', 'Statement 1': 'now', 'Statement 2': 'often', 'Statement 3': 'sometimes', 'Statement 4': 'yes'}]

df = pd.DataFrame(data)
df.to_csv('user_answers.csv', index=False)

print(df)
```

Answer (score 0):

`list of answers` is a list of dictionaries. That means that you should better use a DictWriter here.

```
...
#put the values from the list_of_answers into a csv and store locallyy.
with open('user_answers.csv', 'w', newline='') as myfile:
    wr = csv.DictWriter(myfile, quoting=csv.QUOTE_ALL, fieldnames = 
                        ['Date/time', 'Statement 1', 'Statement 2', 'Statement 3', 'Statement 4'])
    wr.writeheader()
    wr.writerow(list_of_answers)
```